# Is there a way to customize the default TextBox control in UWP? I need to make the 'X' button smaller

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this app in UWP that has a TextBox. By some very complicated constraints, I cannot use anything else but the 'native' TextBox.

I need to remove the X button (or to make it as small as possible), be it in XAML or in C#. After my research I could not find anything apart from creating my own usercontrol, but that's not an option. (it doesn't make much sense to explain why).

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the TextBox's properties though the form? If so, you could comment out the DeleteButtonStyle like this. Hope it's what you are looking at.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!--
            <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            </Style>
            -->
        </Grid.Resources>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is right click on your `TextBox`, click "Edit Template" and then "Edit a Copy".

This should then give you the full template for the `TextBox` control in XAML.

Here is a full copy:

```
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="&#xE10A;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" Margin="0,0,0,8" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsTabStop="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" MinWidth="34" Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Within that code there is a section for the Delete Button and a Font Size of 12 is defined. Simply change this to a smaller number in order to shrink its size then apply the style to your `TextBox` with the following

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" Width="100" Height="50"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have VS Professional 2017, but no "Edit Template" 2017

Comment: That's just a shortcut, you can copy and paste the full code above to achieve the same result.